# How do I integrate google crashpad with my application?

Tags: crash-reports, crash-dumps

The breakpad project will be replaced by the [google crashpad](https://code.google.com/p/crashpad/) project. How do I integrate the new crash reporter with my application on Mac?

Comment: tracking, I also cannot find much documentation...

Comment: I wanted to do the same. I am new to developing android with native code. Is there any update or a tutorial to do the same?

Comment: I am also trying to do that. Were you able to integrate crashpad??

Comment: I have not made any more attempts to use crashpad but I am certainly interested in a tutorial if some one is using crashpad.

Comment: We wrote a tutorial for this the other day. I have copied a snippet from the tutorial below as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 10):

First, configure [depot_tools](https://docs.bugsplat.com/introduction/getting-started/integrations/cross-platform/crashpad/how-to-build-google-crashpad#installing-depot_tools) to build Crashpad.

Next, acquire a copy of the Crashpad [source](https://docs.bugsplat.com/introduction/getting-started/integrations/cross-platform/crashpad/how-to-build-google-crashpad#getting-the-crashpad-source).

Build Crashpad with `gn` and `ninja`, where `gn` generates a build configuration, and `ninja` does the actual building. Full instructions on how to build Crashpad are available [here](https://docs.bugsplat.com/introduction/getting-started/integrations/cross-platform/crashpad/how-to-build-google-crashpad#building-crashpad).

For MacOS, you will need to link against `libclient.a`, `libutil.a`, `libbase.a`, `libcommon.a`, and `libmig_output.a` if you want to generate minidumps and upload them to a remote server. Additionally, you'll need to package `crashpad_handler` with your application and ensure it is available at runtime.

Integrate Crashpad with your application by [configuring](https://docs.bugsplat.com/introduction/getting-started/integrations/cross-platform/crashpad/how-to-build-google-crashpad#configuring-crashpad) the Crashpad handler and point it at a server capable of ingesting Crashpad crash reports.

```
#include "client/crashpad_client.h"
#include "client/crash_report_database.h"
#include "client/settings.h"

#if defined(OS_POSIX)
typedef std::string StringType;
#elif defined(OS_WIN)
typedef std::wstring StringType;
#endif

using namespace base;
using namespace crashpad;
using namespace std;

bool initializeCrashpad(void);
StringType getExecutableDir(void);

bool initializeCrashpad() {
  // Get directory where the exe lives so we can pass a full path to handler, reportsDir and metricsDir
  StringType exeDir = getExecutableDir();
  
  // Ensure that handler is shipped with your application
  FilePath handler(exeDir + "/path/to/crashpad_handler");
  
  // Directory where reports will be saved. Important! Must be writable or crashpad_handler will crash.
  FilePath reportsDir(exeDir + "/path/to/crashpad");
  
  // Directory where metrics will be saved. Important! Must be writable or crashpad_handler will crash.
  FilePath metricsDir(exeDir + "/path/to/crashpad");
  
  // Configure url with BugSplat’s public fred database. Replace 'fred' with the name of your BugSplat database.
  StringType url = "https://fred.bugsplat.com/post/bp/crash/crashpad.php";
  
  // Metadata that will be posted to the server with the crash report map
  map<StringType, StringType> annotations;
  annotations["format"] = "minidump";          // Required: Crashpad setting to save crash as a minidump
  annotations["product"] = "myCrashpadCrasher" // Required: BugSplat appName
  annotations["version"] = "1.0.0";            // Required: BugSplat appVersion
  annotations["key"] = "Sample key";           // Optional: BugSplat key field
  annotations["user"] = "fred@bugsplat.com";   // Optional: BugSplat user email
  annotations["list_annotations"] = "Sample comment"; // Optional: BugSplat crash description
  
  // Disable crashpad rate limiting so that all crashes have dmp files
  vector<StringType> arguments; 
  arguments.push_back("--no-rate-limit");
  
  // Initialize Crashpad database
  unique_ptr<CrashReportDatabase> database = CrashReportDatabase::Initialize(reportsDir);
  if (database == NULL) return false;
  
  // Enable automated crash uploads
  Settings *settings = database->GetSettings();
  if (settings == NULL) return false;
  settings->SetUploadsEnabled(true);
  
  // Start crash handler
  CrashpadClient *client = new CrashpadClient();
  bool status = client->StartHandler(handler, reportsDir, metricsDir, url, annotations, arguments, true, true);
  return status;
}
```

You'll also need to generate sym files using [dump_syms](https://docs.bugsplat.com/introduction/getting-started/integrations/cross-platform/crashpad/how-to-build-google-crashpad#generating-symbols). You can upload sym files to a remote server using [symupload](https://docs.bugsplat.com/introduction/getting-started/integrations/cross-platform/crashpad/how-to-build-google-crashpad#uploading-symbols). Finally, you can symbolicate the minidump using [minidump_stackwalk](https://docs.bugsplat.com/introduction/getting-started/integrations/cross-platform/crashpad/how-to-build-google-crashpad#symbolicating-crash-reports).

Comment: All of your links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

I have just got word from one of the devs that its not ready yet...https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/crashpad-dev/GbS_HcsYzbQ